# JavaScript Toggle button not working for buttons in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

The following JavaScript code toggles HTML buttons. However buttons in a <table> element are not toggled, instead the buttons flash the label "Forget" for a split second. Why are <button> elements in each cell of a table not toggled by the JavaScript code below?

```html
<button class="buttonOne">Connect</button>
<button class="buttonTwo">Connect</button>
<button class="buttonThree">Connect</button>
```

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

let clickedOne = false;
let clickedTwo = false;
let clickedThree = false;
$(".buttonOne").addEventListener("click", (e) => {      
  if (clickedOne) {
    e.target.innerText = "Connect";
  } else {
    e.target.innerText = "Forget";

  }

  clickedOne = !clickedOne;
});

$(".buttonTwo").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (clickedTwo) {
    e.target.innerText = "Connect";
  } else {
    e.target.innerText = "Forget";
  }

  clickedTwo = !clickedTwo;
});

$(".buttonThree").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (clickedThree) {
    e.target.innerText = "Connect";
  } else {
    e.target.innerText = "Forget";
  }

  clickedThree = !clickedThree;
});
```

Comment: I would strongly advise not to use `$` as a variable name as this is often used by popular JavaScript libraries, such as jQuery to denote a specialize object in that library. Also, I'm not sure what you think you are accomplishing with this `const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);` as `document` already exposes the `querySelector()` method.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue; seems to be working in a table element here: https://jsfiddle.net/3bdwLoau/ . can you provide more code?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Okay, that statement is just to get a short hand for the `document.querySelector() method`.

Comment: @sdrm The buttons in my HTML document contained an anchor element with an empty href attribute value (`<a href="">`) which caused the button to flash the label "Forget" when clicked, instead of the button being toggled to "Forget" until it was clicked again. This is why when using the JavaScript code in my question the button was not toggled when clicked.

Comment: This could be also simple prevent by `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @lortschi can you rephrase that?

Comment: I have bellow edited the live example from jsfiddle I posted. There is now an `event.preventDefault()` function provided with empty `<a href=" ">`

Comment: All you have to do to make that shortcut is `const qs = document.querySelector;` You wouldn't bind it to the `document` because it's already a member of `document`.

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the buttons in this way and set the event listener dynamically to each button.

```
<button class="buttonOne">Connect</button>
<button class="buttonTwo">Connect</button>
<button class="buttonThree">Connect</button>


var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

[].slice.call(buttons).forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML == 'Connect') {
      e.target.innerHTML = 'Forget';
    } else {
      e.target.innerHTML = 'Connect';
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/pqtud56k/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could select them by giving unique Id. Example:

```
   <button id="btn1" class="buttonOne">Connect</button>
   <button id="btn2" class="buttonTwo">Connect</button>
   <button id="btn3" class="buttonThree">Connect</button>
```

And select them at your Js file:

```
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');
const btn3 = document.getElementById('btn3');
```

This way you should have no problems with those buttons.